# Online service, NextCloud, is missing

Tags: kubuntu, online-accounts, nextcloud

I recently hoped from KDE Neon, to Kubuntu. My options are missing. The only thing that shows after trying to add an account is OpenDesktop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj2qB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnkg3.png)

Are there ways to add either NextCloud, or other services?

EDIT: I should have added this.

Operating System: Kubuntu 21.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.21.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.80.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.11.0-25-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × Intel® Core™ i7-10870H CPU @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 15.3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics